# Re-arrangement of Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following type of data frame

```
test = {0:['loc_a','loc_b','loc_c'],1:['new_list','new_list','change_list'],2:['abc','abc','abc'],3:['def','change_list','def'],4:['ghi','def','ghi'],5:['change_list','ghi','jkl'],6:['jkl','jkl','mno'],7:['mno','pqr','pqr']}
test = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

[image]

I need to process the dataframe to be in the following form

```
test2 = {'location':['loc_a','loc_a','loc_a','loc_a','loc_a'],'list_type':['new_list','new_list','new_list','change_list','change_list'],'value':['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno']}
test2 = pd.DataFrame(test2)
```

[image]

really need assistance as i'm stuck here , is it possible to transform the data into the desired dataframe form by processing each row ?

Comment: Could you draw what you are trying to do? What is the process that moves the letters in columns 2-7 to the value column?

Comment: We can not help you move all of those columns to a single column without defining why each letter should go in each spot

Comment: on the first row, we have new_list value on column 1 , it indicate the next 3 column (2,3 and 4) fell under this category before the change_list value appear on column 6 where value after column 6 fell under change_list , however the columns location for new_list and change_list might be differ on the next row due to number of values increased or decrease ... , kinda hard to explain but i hope u understand what i'm trying to address ..

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this isn't really the type of data you want to be in a DataFrame to begin with. If you have control of how this data is collected and stored, I would probably try to apply some preprocessing before it is stored into a tabular format. The only solution I can think of involves iterating over the rows and storing the new output to be transformed into a dataframe later.

```
data = []

for row in test.itertuples():
    loc = row[1]
    
    changelist_idx = row.index("change_list") + 1
    try:
        newlist_idx = row.index("new_list") + 1
    except ValueError:
        newlist_idx = changelist_idx
    
    newlist_values = row[newlist_idx:changelist_idx - 1]
    changelist_values = row[changelist_idx:]
    
    for value in newlist_values:
        data.append([loc, "new_list", value])
    for value in changelist_values:
        data.append([loc, "change_list", value])
    
out = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["location", "list_type", "value"])
print(out)

   location    list_type value
0     loc_a     new_list   abc
1     loc_a     new_list   def
2     loc_a     new_list   ghi
3     loc_a  change_list   jkl
4     loc_a  change_list   mno
5     loc_b     new_list   abc
6     loc_b  change_list   def
7     loc_b  change_list   ghi
8     loc_b  change_list   jkl
9     loc_b  change_list   pqr
10    loc_c  change_list   abc
11    loc_c  change_list   def
12    loc_c  change_list   ghi
13    loc_c  change_list   jkl
14    loc_c  change_list   mno
15    loc_c  change_list   pqr
```

Answer (score 1):

The data requires some reshaping to get the form you want; primarily, you need to `melt`, do a `groupby` (ensure that it is not sorted, so the current order is preserved) :

I would suggest you run each line independently so that you can understand each stage of the transformation; you could even come up with a better way or even get rid of unnecessary steps :

```
(
    test.melt(0)
    .groupby(0, sort=False)["value"]
    .agg(",".join)
    .str.split(",")
    .explode()
    .rename_axis("location")
    .reset_index()
    .assign(list_type=lambda x: x.loc[x["value"].str.contains("list"), "value"])
    .ffill()
    .query("value!=list_type")
)



  location  value   list_type
1   loc_a   abc     new_list
2   loc_a   def     new_list
3   loc_a   ghi     new_list
5   loc_a   jkl     change_list
6   loc_a   mno     change_list
8   loc_b   abc     new_list
10  loc_b   def     change_list
11  loc_b   ghi     change_list
12  loc_b   jkl     change_list
13  loc_b   pqr     change_list
15  loc_c   abc     change_list
16  loc_c   def     change_list
17  loc_c   ghi     change_list
18  loc_c   jkl     change_list
19  loc_c   mno     change_list
20  loc_c   pqr     change_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple answer using pandas `.iterrows()`. I hope for your reference.

```python
# Collect the items you want to stack in a list.
test['lst'] = test[range(1, 8)].values.tolist()

df_all = pd.DataFrame()
# Create the desired DataFrame for each location.
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    loc = row[0]
    df_by_loc = pd.DataFrame()
    for lst in row['lst']:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'location': [loc]})
        # If lst is 'new_list' or 'change_list', create list_type.
        if lst is 'new_list':
            list_type = 'new_list'
        elif lst is 'change_list':
            list_type = 'change_list'
        else:
            # In cases other than the above, the item of 'list_type' and 'value' is actually created.
            df['list_type'] = list_type
            df['value'] = lst
        
        # Create a DataFrame for each location by concating.
        if lst not in ['new_list', 'change_list']:
            df_by_loc = pd.concat([df_by_loc, df], axis=0)
    
    df_all = pd.concat([df_all, df_by_loc], axis=0)
```

The results are as follows.

```python
print(df_all)
  location    list_type value
0    loc_a     new_list   abc
0    loc_a     new_list   def
0    loc_a     new_list   ghi
0    loc_a  change_list   jkl
0    loc_a  change_list   mno
0    loc_b     new_list   abc
0    loc_b  change_list   def
0    loc_b  change_list   ghi
0    loc_b  change_list   jkl
0    loc_b  change_list   pqr
0    loc_c  change_list   abc
0    loc_c  change_list   def
0    loc_c  change_list   ghi
0    loc_c  change_list   jkl
0    loc_c  change_list   mno
0    loc_c  change_list   pqr
```